# React.js array.map does not return jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a mobx store from where I am pulling an array of data and trying to render each as an `<li>`

```
 let completedList = completedTodos.map(todo => { <li> {todo.value} </li> } );
```

I can't figure out why this does not return anything but undefined.

Sorry I am new here and this is probably a dumb question.

Comment: you are not returning anything inside `map` body use this: `let completedList = completedTodos.map(todo => <li> {todo.value} </li> );` or use `return` to return the html element, like this: ``let completedList = completedTodos.map(todo => {return <li> {todo.value} </li> });``

Comment: @blackmind check my first comment again, i mentioned both ways :)

Comment: This worked perfect. Thanks for showing me the way.

Comment: For reference this is how I got my code to work. render(){ let completedList = completedTodos.map(todo => <li> {todo.value} </li>); return ( <div> <h1>todos</h1> {completedList} </div> ) }

Answer (score 4):

Easy mistake! Your arrow function should use parentheses () instead of brackets {} if you don't explicitly use `return`.

```
let completedList = completedTodos.map(todo => (<p>{todo.value}</p>));
```

Otherwise, you can skip the parens entirely - the arrow function without brackets implies a `return`.

```
let completedList = completedTodos.map(todo => <p>{todo.value}</p>);
```

Comment: You can also just do `completedTodos.map(todo => <p>{todo.value}</p>);` but good catch on the {}

Comment: Yep, @mayank-shukla and @blackmind are right - you don't even need the parens 

`let completedList = completedTodos.map(todo => <p>{todo.value}</p> );`